Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version
I'm trying to run a Flutter app in Windows, and also tried to run in a Android device.
And it keeps givin the same error:
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/myProject/build/windows/x64/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk_windows/CMakeLists.txt:17 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.

Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.

...

Error: Build process failed.

Exited (1).

In the local files gives error GDC1E81E8.
I did the chache repairing:
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub chache repair

But it not worked.

I did the flutter Downgrade to the version 3.22.2, the app run, but it freezes on the splash screen
